How to truncate text in latex?
I have a long string of text that I want to shorten for example truncate hash
21dce451e8ddc5e054cf2019511570c3618f871ab0d25c2b12b7c878f3038355

to
21dce...8355

how to do it?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Under the assumption that the input can be stringified without issue (so no macros, and no non-ASCII characters if used in pdfTeX) the following gives a flexible function to shorten your strings.
It'll check if the number of characters in the input is bigger than twice the number of characters to use from either end, if there are it'll do the truncation, else leave the input as result. You can change the symbol to use as a separator of the two groups via an optional argument.
EDIT: I've added another optional argument after the number of characters to be used that can be used to set a different number of characters to be used at the end of the string (defaulting to the one to be taken at the start).
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \konto_truncate:nnnn #1#2#3#4
  {
    \int_compare:nNnTF { \str_count:n {#1} } > { #3 + #4 }
      {
        \str_range:nnn {#1} {1} {#3}
        #2
        \str_range:nnn {#1} {-#4} {-1}
      }
      {#1}
  }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \truncate { O{\ldots} m O{#2} m }
  { \konto_truncate:nnnn {#4} {#1} {#2} {#3} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\truncate{5}{21dce451e8ddc5e054cf2019511570c3618f871ab0d25c2b12b7c878f3038355}\par
\truncate{4}[5]{21dce451e8ddc5e054cf2019511570c3618f871ab0d25c2b12b7c878f3038355}\par
\truncate{3}{21dce451e8ddc5e054cf2019511570c3618f871ab0d25c2b12b7c878f3038355}\par
\truncate{3}{21dce4}\par
\end{document}

(image is the old results without the use of the optional argument)


You can also make use \StrLeft and \StrRight from the xstring pacakge:

The \TruncateHash{} macro below will show the first 5 digits and the last 4 digits. These two paramaters can be adjusted based on the optional first two parameters:
\TruncateHash[<left digit count>][<right digits count>]{<hash>}

Code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\NewDocumentCommand{\TruncateHash}{%
    O{5}% #1 = number of digits to show on left (defaults to 5)
    O{4}% #2 = number of digits to show on right (defaults to 4)
    m%    #3 = hash
}{%
    \StrLeft{#3}{#1}\ldots\StrRight{#3}{#2}%
}%

\begin{document}
\TruncateHash{21dce451e8ddc5e054cf2019511570c3618f871ab0d25c2b12b7c878f3038355}

\TruncateHash[3][3]{21dce451e8ddc5e054cf2019511570c3618f871ab0d25c2b12b7c878f3038355}
\end{document}


As the hash has a (presumably) fixed length, you can just drop the middle characters 9 at a time.

\documentclass{article}

\def\foo#1{\fooa#1}
\def\fooa#1#2#3#4{#1#2#3#4\ldots\foob}
\def\foob#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9{\fooc}
\def\fooc#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9{\food}
\def\food#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9{\fooe}
\def\fooe#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9{\foof}
\def\foof#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9{\foog}
\def\foog#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9{\fooh}
\def\fooh#1#2{}

\begin{document}
21dce451e8ddc5e054cf2019511570c3618f871ab0d25c2b12b7c878f3038355

\foo{21dce451e8ddc5e054cf2019511570c3618f871ab0d25c2b12b7c878f3038355}

\end{document}


If your strings have predetermined length 64, you can use \easytruncatehash, that allows no run-time customization.
Otherwise, I propose a more general \truncatehash command that accepts an optional argument in the form m-n, where m is the number of leading characters and n is the number of trailing ones. The default is 5-4. If just one number is specified, the same will be used for leading and trailing characters. However, if the sum is greater than the length of the string, the full string will be returned.
In order to ensure full expandability, a function providing the \dots separator has to be added.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Nn \konto_trunchash_sep: { \dots }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\easytruncatehash}{m}
 {
  \str_range:nnn {#1} {1} {5}
  \konto_trunchash_sep:
  \str_range:nnn {#1} {-4} {-1}
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\truncatehash}{O{5-4}m}
 {
  \konto_trunchash:een
   { \__konto_trunchash_left:n {#1} }
   { \__konto_trunchash_right:n {#1} }
   {#2}
 }

\cs_new:Nn \konto_trunchash:nnn
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { #1+#2 > \str_count:n {#3} }
   {% no truncation
    #3
   }
   {% truncate
    \str_range:nnn {#3} {1} {#1}
    \konto_trunchash_sep:
    \str_range:nnn {#3} {-#2} {-1}
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \konto_trunchash:nnn {ee}

\cs_new:Nn \__konto_trunchash_left:n
 {
  \__konto_trunchash_left_aux:w #1--\q_stop
 }
\cs_new:Npn \__konto_trunchash_left_aux:w #1-#2-#3\q_stop {#1}

\cs_new:Nn \__konto_trunchash_right:n
 {
  \__konto_trunchash_right_aux:w #1--\q_stop
 }
\cs_new:Npn \__konto_trunchash_right_aux:w #1-#2-#3\q_stop
 {
  \tl_if_empty:nTF {#2} {#1} {#2}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\easytruncatehash{21dce451e8ddc5e054cf2019511570c3618f871ab0d25c2b12b7c878f3038355}

\truncatehash{21dce451e8ddc5e054cf2019511570c3618f871ab0d25c2b12b7c878f3038355}

\truncatehash[4]{21dce451e8ddc5e054cf2019511570c3618f871ab0d25c2b12b7c878f3038355}

\truncatehash[4-3]{21dce451e8ddc5e054cf2019511570c3618f871ab0d25c2b12b7c878f3038355}

\truncatehash[64]{21dce451e8ddc5e054cf2019511570c3618f871ab0d25c2b12b7c878f3038355}

\end{document}



For the sake of variety, a LuaLaTeX-based solution.
Note that the Lua function str_truncate deliberately uses unicode.utf8.len and unicode.utf8.sub, rather than the "basic" Lua string functions string.len and string.sub, in order to assure that the LaTeX macro \StrTruncate isn't restricted to using ASCII-encoded strings. Indeed, utf8-encoded strings are fine.

% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\directlua{

  function str_trunc ( s )
    if unicode.utf8.len ( s ) > 12 then
      return ( unicode.utf8.sub(s,1,5) .. "..." .. unicode.utf8.sub(s,-4) )
    else % -- "s" isn't long enough to be truncated
      return ( s )
    end
  end

}
\newcommand\StrTruncate[1]{\directlua{ tex.sprint ( str_trunc ("#1")) }}

\begin{document}
\StrTruncate{21dce451e8ddc5e054cf2019511570c3618f871ab0d25c2b12b7c878f3038355}
\end{document}


The expl3 offerings aren't restricted to ASCII in general, only with 8-bit engines :) (One could avoid that, but it would be more painful)

@JosephWright - Sorry for not being sufficiently clear in my write-up. The remark about the proposed solution not being restricted to ASCII-encoded characters was not intended as a veiled comment about the expl3 offerings. Instead, it was solely meant to point out that the str_trunc function deliberately uses unicode.utf8.len and unicode.utf8.sub instead of string.len and string.sub in order not to be restricted to working with ASCII-encoded strings.
